# How can I use Python rank() with same-values' counts?

Tags: python, pandas, rank

I am dealing with a dataframe in python.

Here is what I want to do.

```
1. same value gets same rank
2. the next rank should be added as much as the same rank counts
```

this is what I intended

- price  rank
- 5300   1
- 5300   1
- 5300   1
- 5200   4 < previous rank: 1 + counts of 5300s: 3
- 5200   4 < same value, same rank
- 5100   6 < previous rank: 4 + counts of 5200s: 2

First, I tried to use rank(method = "dense") function. But it did not work as I expected.

df_sales["rank"] = df_sales["price"].rank(ascending = False, method = "dense")

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example input and expected output?

Comment: I inserted an image a minute age. thank you

Comment: welcome to SO. If you ask abstract questions you will get no answer. Sharpen your question. Use what you have and show your expected result.

Comment: @john Examples in text in the body of the question itself are much preferred over links to images.

Comment: _"I inserted an image a minute ago"_. You should not post [images of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), since people cant use it to reproduce anything.

Comment: @glibdud thank you for the tip. This is my first question. I tried to draw a table in the text, But It ignored new line character :(

Comment: You need `method='min'` and `ascending=False`: `df['r'] = df['x'].rank(method='min', ascending=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `method='min'` and `ascending=False`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[5300,5300,5300,5200,5200, 5100]})
df['r'] = df['x'].rank(method='min', ascending=False)
```

From [`pandas.Series.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html)

> method : {‘average’, ‘min’, ‘max’, ‘first’, ‘dense’}
>
> ```
>     average: average rank of group
>     min: lowest rank in group
>     max: highest rank in group
>     first: ranks assigned in order they appear in the array
>     dense: like ‘min’, but rank always increases by 1 between groups
> ```

Note that `dense` specifically increases rank by 1 within groups. You want the `min` option.

Comment: Thank you for your time. It works beautifully. How come I don't think about 'min' option? Have a great day!